# how to prevent mobile web browser timeout? I want to keep client connected to socket.io server

Tags: node.js, mobile, browser, socket.io, client

When a client connects to a node.js socket.io server via a mobile device web browser. Once the client turns off the screen on their mobile device, after X time, the client gets disconnected.

Is the mobile web browser automatically silencing network traffic or is the mobile phone silencing the web browsers network traffic?

I'm looking for a solution to keep the connection alive while the mobile device is inactive/screen off.

Other details:
I tested this with different mobile web browsers and had the same issue. Using a regular desktop browser as a client works fine.